# What do do with this deck area over the crawlspace

Tags: waterproofing, water-damage, crawlspace

[image]
[image]

Hi - I've recently had to rebuild the corner of my house due to this porch design that was built directly over the crawlspace (terrible design IMO) and eventually allowed water to come in around the corner facing the camera.

I now need to decide on the best way to keep this area dry, there is no external roof - just the 1ft overhang from the eaves that you can see. I initially thought about extending the house out onto this corner - but that is too much work for now, so I'm now thinking about a heavily waterproofed non-slip "roof" with a 1 inch drop towards the outer edge with an overhang.

What would you recommend here?